# Uploading area KML to GeoDjango MultiPolygonField

Tags: python, postgis, geodjango

I have a model

```py
class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    point = postgis.PointField(null = True, blank = True)
    area = postgis.MultiPolygonField(null = True, blank = True)
```

I have a KML file which consist of different areas and I want to upload it into this model so later I can add the foreign key of the area in other table

How to do that?